# Is there a way to put a Public LB in front of Application Gateay?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

I want to use an Azure Application Gateway with a static IP address. Since Application Gateway doesn't support public IP, I thought I'd try using a private Application Gateway and putting a public LB in front of it.  However, I can't seem to find a way to send the traffic from the LB to Application Gateway.

So I was wondering if there is a way to send traffic from an LB to an Application Gateway?  If not, is there another way of having a static IP address with Azure Application Gateway?

Comment: Because I clicked on it on accident.  Haven't had any time to read either answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

Application Gateway does not support static public IP addresses, but it does support **static internal IPs.** [This](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/20531968-allow-static-public-ip-address) is part of the product roadmap. Also, here is App GW [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq).

> The VIP can change if the gateway is stopped and started by the
>   customer. The DNS associated with Application Gateway does not change
>   over the lifecycle of the gateway. For this reason, it is recommended
>   to use a CNAME alias and point it to the DNS address of the
>   Application Gateway.

So if APP GW keeps running, It looks like static IP for you when you use APP GW to offer various layer 7 load balancing capabilities for your applications. It offers a highly available and scalable service, which is fully managed by Azure. Also, you can create an APP GW + ILB.

Ref: [Create an application gateway with an internal load balancer (ILB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-ilb-arm)

### Update

As of today, It's impossible to put a static public IP address in front of the application gateway, but you can have a static internal IP address which you can specify it.

You can create it on the portal or with PowerShell as [the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/new-azurermapplicationgatewayfrontendipconfig?view=azurermps-6.8.1).

```
$VNet = Get-AzureRmvirtualNetwork -Name "VNet01" -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01"
$Subnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name "Subnet01" -VirtualNetwork $VNet
$FrontEnd = New-AzureRmApplicationGatewayFrontendIPConfig -Name "FrontendIP02" -Subnet $Subnet -PrivateIPAddress 10.0.1.1
```

You need the [Azure RM Powershell 6.8.1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM/6.8.1) when you run the above scripts.

Comment: Yes, I knew all this by reading the documents.  That is why I'm asking a question about how to put an LB in front, which can have a static IP address.

Comment: Azure LB is a layer-4 load balancing, which enables you to distribute TCP/UDP traffic from frontend to backend for VM, VM scale sets or availability sets instead of a web app. So I don't think there is a way to put an azure LB in front. App GW is also a layer-7 load balancing which distributes traffic for the web app. As I said in my above reply, now the static public IP is in a product roadmap or you can use it since the VIP does not change until the gateway is stopped.

Comment: If you're sure to get a static IP for App GW. You can create an APP GW with Private IP as the frontend. You can have a glance at [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm.md#at-a-glance). Static internal IP is support for App GW.

Comment: Most of this is already in the documents.  My question is really around an undocumented way of putting an LB in front of AGW.  I know that AGW will keep it's IP unless the gateway is stopped but I would still like to have a static IP and not a dynamic IP.  So I am trying to find a way to put a static IP(maybe LB, maybe something else?) in front of an internal AGW, if possible.

Comment: well, got it, I will escalate your question, will reply back if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an API Management Service instead of a load balancer. Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-faq):  "In all tiers of API Management, the public IP address (VIP) of the API Management tenant is static for the lifetime of the tenant, with some exceptions." Here's a potentially helpful how-to [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put an LB in front of Application Gateway. Application Gateway has a new SKU in public preview which allows use of Static VIP. This is documented [here](http://aka.ms/appgw-autoscale-preview).

Answer (score 0):

Application gateway with Static IP is supported in V2 SKU. If you deploy a new Application gateway and select either Standardv2 or WAFv2 SKU, you can have a static IP address to your Application gateway.

FAQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq

Does Application Gateway support static IP?
*Yes, the Application Gateway v2 SKU does support static public IP addresses. The v1 SKU supports static internal IPs.*